# The chrome mobile ver. at iphone had weird viewport behavior when I open website by target="_blank"

Tags: html, css, styles, google-chrome-app

**[Update]**
I had rebuild the issue below:

https://sp0033212000.github.io/fixedProblem/

---

I had a site.

I was work well except open it by target _blank.

When I into the site directly, it normal
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfrWC.jpg)

but when I into it by new tab, the bottom button was be covered.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lat6Z.jpg)

I guest it was viewport issue but no idea how to fix it.

could some one give me suggest how to handle this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try giving z-index to the button.

```html
.btn{
  z-index:999;
  }
```

Comment: this is not the layer issue, is about viewport.
I had built a testing env. You could try it.